# Jquery Move custom tabs to next

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

i have some basic html/css tabs and i want want to move tab to next by clicking a link at bottom of every tab.

HTML

```
 <ul class="tabs">
   <li class="active">
      <a href="#">Explainer (2mins)</a>
      <div class="content">
         <div id="Video" class="tabcontent">
            <div class="coltab">
               content A
            </div>
            <h4>Next tab: View Some Sample Lessons</h4>
         </div>
      </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#">Sample Lessons</a>
      <div class="content coltab">
         <div>
            Content B
         </div>
         <h4> Next tab: See the Your Offer. </h4>
      </div>
   </li>

</ul>
```

Jquery for this is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tabs").after("<div class='tabContent'></div>");

    $(".tabs li>a").on("click", function(e){
        var $tab = $(this).parent();
        var tabIndex = $tab.index();

        $tab.parent("ul").find("li").removeClass("active");
        $tab.addClass("active");

        var tabContent = $tab.find(">div").clone(true);
        $(".tabContent").html(tabContent);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

it is working fine for me now as i click on tab its changes.

Live demo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".tabs").after("<div class='tabContent'></div>");
 
 $(".tabs li>a").on("click", function(e){
  var $tab = $(this).parent();
  var tabIndex = $tab.index();
  
  $tab.parent("ul").find("li").removeClass("active");
  $tab.addClass("active");
  
  var tabContent = $tab.find(">div").clone(true);
  $(".tabContent").html(tabContent);
  e.preventDefault();
 });
 
});
```

```css
.coltab{
 height: 51vh;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
.tabs {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border-top: 1px solid #000;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: table;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
 .tabs li {
 display: table-cell;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
.tabs li>a {
 display: block;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5px;
}
.tabs li>a:hover,.tabs li.active a {
 background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

.tabs li .content {
 display: none;
}

.tabContent {
 padding: 15px 15px 0px 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
   <li class="active">
      <a href="#">Explainer (2mins)</a>
      <div class="content">
         <div id="Video" class="tabcontent">
            <div class="coltab">
               content A
            </div>
            <h4>Next tab: View Some Sample Lessons</h4>
         </div>
      </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#">Sample Lessons</a>
      <div class="content coltab">
         <div>
            Content B
         </div>
         <h4> Next tab: See the Your Offer. </h4>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#">Special Offer</a>
      <div class="content">
         <div class="coltab">
            Content C
         </div>
         <h4>Next tab: To Register and Subscribe>>></h4>
      </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#">Subscribe</a>
      <div class="content coltab">
        <div>
         Content D
      </div>
        <div>
      <h4>Next tab: To Request a callback</h4>
      </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#">Request a Callback</a>
      <div class="content coltab">
         <div>
            Content E
         </div>
         <h4>Next tab: Reviews</h4>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#">Reviews</a>
      <div class="content">
         <div>
            Content F
         </div>
         <h4>Back to first tab</h4>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this code:

```
$("h4").click(function(){
  var activeTab = $("ul.tabs > li.active");
  var nextTab = (activeTab.is(':last-child') == true ? $("ul.tabs > li:first") : $("ul.tabs > li.active").next("li"));
  nextTab.find("a").trigger("click")
});
```

it will allow you to click on the `h4` aka next and move to the next content

**Working demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".tabs").after("<div class='tabContent'></div>");
 
 $(".tabs li>a").on("click", function(e){
  var $tab = $(this).parent();
  var tabIndex = $tab.index();
  
  $tab.parent("ul").find("li").removeClass("active");
  $tab.addClass("active");
  
  var tabContent = $tab.find(">div").clone(true);
  $(".tabContent").html(tabContent);
  e.preventDefault();
 });
 
  $("h4").click(function(){
    var activeTab = $("ul.tabs > li.active");
    var nextTab = (activeTab.is(':last-child') == true ? $("ul.tabs > li:first") : $("ul.tabs > li.active").next("li"));
    nextTab.find("a").trigger("click")
  });
});
```

```css
.coltab{
 height: 51vh;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
.tabs {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border-top: 1px solid #000;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: table;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
 .tabs li {
 display: table-cell;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
.tabs li>a {
 display: block;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5px;
}
.tabs li>a:hover,.tabs li.active a {
 background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

.tabs li .content {
 display: none;
}

.tabContent {
 padding: 15px 15px 0px 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
   <li class="active">
      <a href="#">Explainer (2mins)</a>
      <div class="content">
         <div id="Video" class="tabcontent">
            <div class="coltab">
               content A
            </div>
            <h4>Next tab: View Some Sample Lessons</h4>
         </div>
      </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#">Sample Lessons</a>
      <div class="content coltab">
         <div>
            Content B
         </div>
         <h4> Next tab: See the Your Offer. </h4>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#">Special Offer</a>
      <div class="content">
         <div class="coltab">
            Content C
         </div>
         <h4>Next tab: To Register and Subscribe>>></h4>
      </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#">Subscribe</a>
      <div class="content coltab">
        <div>
         Content D
      </div>
        <div>
      <h4>Next tab: To Request a callback</h4>
      </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#">Request a Callback</a>
      <div class="content coltab">
         <div>
            Content E
         </div>
         <h4>Next tab: Reviews</h4>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#">Reviews</a>
      <div class="content">
         <div>
            Content F
         </div>
         <h4>Back to first tab</h4>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```